# Check if file exists anywhere on the system...?

Tags: java, file, io

If I am in a directory deep within the file structure, how do I check if a file exists somewhere way up the file tree (like anywhere on the system)? I am trying to use the exists() file, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Ex: If the root directory has four sub directories: a, b, c, and d. And dir a has file a.txt. If dir d has three sub dirs, and I am currently in the farthest sub dir. If I do something like (new File("a.txt")).exists(), it says the file doesn't exist. Therefore, I want to know how to find if a file exists in a super directory that can be anywhere on the system.

Edit: For the example, if I don't know the directory where the file exists, and just the file name, how do you see if it exists?

I am new to Java, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing the code yourself and seeing if it worked? A little effort goes a long way.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. i want to know how to see if a file exists in a super directory

Comment: Well, use an absolute path: `new File("/a/a.txt")`, or a relative one: `new File("../../a/a.txt")`. You need to learn about file paths in general: this is not limited to Java.

Comment: What if I don't know the absolute path, and just the file name?

Comment: Well, in that case, you'll have to scan the whole disk to find it. But this is really not something you want to do. So change your design so that you don't have to do that. BTW, how would you know that it's the correct a.txt file: there could be many of them on the file system.

Comment: the a.txt was just a very simplified example

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes in combination with Java 8's [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). The `Files` class contains a `walk` method that will go through the files and directories.

```
Path root = Paths.get("/path/to/root");
boolean result = Files.walk(root)
                      .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                      .anyMatch(p -> p.endsWith("a.txt"));
```

Note that `endsWith` does a match on the full filename, if the file is called `bla.txt` it won't be matched.

If you need to *find* the file you can do the following:

```
Optional<Path> result = Files.walk(root)
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .filter(p -> p.endsWith("a.txt"))
            .findAny();

if (result.isPresent()) {
  // do something with the file
} else {
  // whoopsie, not found
}
```

if there are multiple files you want to find you can do the following:

```
List<Path> result = Files.walk(root)
                         .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                         .filter(p -> p.endsWith("a.txt"))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
   ... do smth with the paths
} else {
   ... whoopsie, not found
}
```

You can also process the found files directly if you want:

```
Files.walk(root)
     .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
     .filter(p -> p.endsWith("a.txt"))
     .forEach(this::process); 


private void process(Path path) {
   // do smth with the path
}
```

...

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, Path root = Files.get("/"); doesn't work for me. Could you tell me why please?

Comment: My bad, it is `Paths.get`, will fix the answer. If you are on windows you might need to include the drive letter.